# string indices must be integers, not str - django

Tags: python, json, django, post

I am trying to pass this into a post from front end but I keep on getting this error on this line and I cannot figure out why is that

`{"isUpdated": true}` passing this

in my django, I have these

```
    body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
    data = json.loads(body_unicode)

    if data['isUpdated'] is not False:
     # more codes
```

I keep on getting error on this `if data['isUpdated'] is not False:`

Can someone give me suggestions what is happening?

Comment: Maybe it will encode "true" as a str. Check the value of data and the type of `data['isUpdated']`

Comment: What is value of `body_unicode` before parsing this data.?

Comment: @Algorithmatic value is True, and type is bol

Comment: @Tsuna what is the error you get?

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz it was `{"isUpdated": true}`

Comment: @Algorithmatic `if data['isUpdated'] is not False:
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str`

Comment: What is difference in values or types of `body_unicode` and `data`?

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz if I do `print(type(body_unicode['isUpdated']))
TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz `body_unicode` is unicode and `data` is dict.  I tried using `data = json.loads(str(body_unicode))`  and still no luck

Comment: if you have logged the type of `data` which is dict then what is that value. why not update your question, give more data about values and types before and after parsing.

Answer (score 0):

The `string indices must be integers, not str` error means that the `data` variable contains a string, and Python is complaining that it cannot use a string to access the characters contained in that string (`data[0]` would return the first character, `data[1]` would return the second character and so on, but what would `data['isUpdated']` return?)

What does the request body contain? Just the text of the post, or a JSON object?